# Not able to download file with UTF-8 character in java servlet

Tags: java, html, servlet-3.0

I am trying to download the excel file with Japanese/Chinese character. It look like it works on IE 8 only and not on firefox.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich That's the worst advice I ever heard.

Comment: How is your download routine implemented?

Comment: @MCEmperor: but without any more details than this, it's the best advice possible IMO. He only needs to use it for the one file.

Comment: Probably a [mcve] would help.

Comment: Excel is a binary file. So I'm a bit confused about the mention of UTF-8 character set. Maybe the file is read as text instead of raw binary? But without the code it is impossible to be sure.

Comment: You haven’t told us how you’re trying to download it.  Are you trying to use Java code to download it?  Are you trying to use a browser to download a file from a servlet you wrote?  If we don’t know what you’re doing, how can suggest how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code .

```
String fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName);
```